# logind.conf change automatically to default values

Tags: 18.04, lid, systemd-logind

My laptop recently did not go to sleep mode when I close the lid. So I looked `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file and configuration was `#HandleLidSwitch=ignore`. Then I uncommented it and change the value to `HandleLidSwitch=suspend`. After restarting the logind service It works fine. But after some time It reverts back to `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` this and I have to edit that again and again. What is the reason for that and is there any other workaround to resolve that?

Comment: Can any one answer this?

Comment: did you find the reason?

Comment: Not actually, I reinstalled the ubuntu :|